# How to resolve python keyerror

Tags: python, json

I practice python json. But I have some problem my code.

It's Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\�ڵ���\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\f495f790-8c51-11ea-a439-1ba828893305", line 45, in 
    num = len(movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"])
KeyError: 'movieListResult'

How to resolve this error?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd

movieIdListURL = 
"http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/boxoffice/searchDailyBoxOfficeList.json? 
key=430156241533f1d058c603178cc3ca0e&targetDt=20120101&openStartDt=2020&itemPerPage=20"

movieIdPage = urlopen(movieIdListURL)
movieIdData = json.loads(movieIdPage.read())

movieIDDF = pd.DataFrame()
movieIDDF = movieIDDF.append(
{"movieCd":"","movieNm":"","movieNmEn":"","openDt":"","peopleNm":""},
ignore_index= True)



num = len(movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"])
print (num)
for i in range(0,num):
    movieIDDF.ix[i,"movieCd"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["movieCd"]
    movieIDDF.ix[i,"movieNm"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["movieNm"]
    movieIDDF.ix[i,"movieNmEn"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["movieNmEn"]
    movieIDDF.ix[i,"openDt"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["openDt"]
    if movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["directors"] != []:
        movieIDDF.ix[i,"peopleNm"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["directors"][0]["peopleNm"]
    else:
        movieIDDF.ix[i,"peopleNm"] = ""
```

Comment: The loaded JSON as no `"movieListResult"` key. Maybe you could try `movieIdData["boxOfficeResult"]["dailyBoxOfficeList"]`. And beware `"movieNmEn"` also seems not to be present...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you. Your comment was helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check if movieListResult in the movieIdData dict keys before calling it

```
if "movieListResult" in movieIdData:
    num = len(movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"])
    print (num)
    for i in range(0,num):
        movieIDDF.ix[i,"movieCd"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["movieCd"]
        movieIDDF.ix[i,"movieNm"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["movieNm"]
        movieIDDF.ix[i,"movieNmEn"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["movieNmEn"]
        movieIDDF.ix[i,"openDt"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["openDt"]
        if movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["directors"] != []:
            movieIDDF.ix[i,"peopleNm"] = movieIdData["movieListResult"]["movieList"][i]["directors"][0]["peopleNm"]
        else:
            movieIDDF.ix[i,"peopleNm"] = ""
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your dataframe does not have a key 'movieListResult'. Try logging the keys of movieIdData (by for example print(movieIdData.keys()) and check which keys are in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer was helpful to me